# Running java from its built Jar file (the alternative way)

Tags: java, jar, war

IS there a non process blocking equivalent for the command :

```
Java -jar target/filename.war
```

Thanks

Comment: What do  you mean by "non process blocking equivalent"? Do you mean just adding `&` to the end of the command to put it in the background, ie `java -jar target/filename.war&`

Comment: maybe pls elaborate

Comment: I'm asking you to elaborate. I don't understand your question.

Comment: i want the current cmd to be a non process blocking one, running in the background seems to be a good idea so how to do it ?

Comment: alright no spaces just a & ?

Comment: `java -jar target/filename.war&` (assuming *nix)

Comment: space, no space, whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command would help

```
nohup java -jar target/filename.war &
```

output (console) will be available at nohup.out.

Comment: is there any other solution (alternative in case this doesnt work)